# How to execute two BASH shell commands from a single test?

Tags: linux, bash

Why does this not work?

```
test $? -eq 1 || $(echo "hello"; echo "hi")
```

I get the following error:

```
Command 'hello' not found, but can be installed with:
snap install hello              # version 2.10, or
apt  install hello              # version 2.10-2ubuntu4
apt  install hello-traditional  # version 2.10-5
See 'snap info hello' for additional versions.
```

Comment: Ofc I could write both statements in a single echo command; I'm just trying to simulate running two commands.

Comment: Because there is nothing in your PATH, function, alias with the name `hello` and `hi`? The `$()` is called `command substitution` it execute whatever is the output of the command inside it. In your case `hello` and `hi`

Comment: How do I echo something to the screen then?

Comment: _How do I echo something to the screen then?_ `printf '%s %s\n' hello hi`

Comment: I never knew this, thank you much.

Comment: Put a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: This doesn't work either though -- test $? -eq 1 || $(printf '%s %s' hello hi)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250176/discussion-between-jetchisel-and-gary).

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [3.2.5.3 Grouping Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping)

```bash
test $? -eq 1 || { echo "hello"; echo "hi"; }
```

The spaces around the braces and the trailing semicolon (or newline) are required.

---

However, don't test the exit status with the `$?` variable (it's too easy to accidentally insert another command in there)

Use the command directly

```bash
some command here && { echo hello; echo hi; }
```